# C# Unable to connect to localhost

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm writing a very simple .NET `TCP Server` and very simple `TCP Client` that should both run on the same machine (Window 10 Home PC) and connect each other (for testing purposes only).
In the server I'm waiting for the connection in this way:

```cs
public static void StartListening()
{
    string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Properties.Settings.Default.Port);

    Socket listener = new Socket(
        ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(Properties.Settings.Default.Port);

        while (true)
        {
            allDone.Reset();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener);

            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();
}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    allDone.Set();

    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

    var frames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.FramesPath);

    foreach (string filename in frames)
    {
        Console.Write("Sending frame: {}...", filename);
        SendFile(handler, filename);
        Thread.Sleep(Properties.Settings.Default.FrameDelay);
    }
}
```

In the client I'm creating a connection in this way:

```cs
private void startClient(string host, int port)
{
    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port);

    ClientTCP = new TcpClient();

    ClientTCP.Connect(serverEndPoint);

    Reader = new StreamReader(ClientTCP.GetStream());

    Listen = true;

    listner = Listener();
}
```

`startClient` is called in this way.

```cs
startClient(txtAddr.Text, (int)int.Parse(txtPort.Text));
```

When I run the client setting `host` variable to the current machine name (the same the server retrieve trough `Dns.GetHostName()` I got this exception:

> An invalid ip address was specified.

I tried using *127.0.0.1* and I got:

> Connection could not be established. Persistent rejection of the target computer 127.0.0.1:5002

I tried with *localhost* and I got

> An invalid ip address was specified

again. I tried with the IP address assigned to WiFi and I got again

> Connection could not be established. Persistent rejection of the target computer 192.168.10.11:5002

I'm sure the computer network works since I'm using it for many other things including connecting to local TCP services and I'm sure both client and server code works since on a different PC I'm able to connect them setting *localhost* as client `host` variable value. Why I'm unable to use loopback connections in my code?

Where did I fail?

P.S. I allowed connection to server binary in Windows firewall rules, I also allowed outgoing connection for client binary also.

For anyone willing to inspect the server code here it is:

[Server code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yuqt8UBmIMCE19eIDYjcoIN_ub9Ej0-d?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm running only Windows Firewall and I allowed server incoming connection...

Comment: This exact code can't have ever worked with `localhost` -- the `An invalid ip address was specified.` message is an exception thrown by `IPAddress.Parse()` when given `localhost` as the IP address.

Comment: @Herohtar Why should I lie? I'm sure the code is the same. Maybe network settings of the two PC are different (the working machine is a Windows 10 Pro with a business settings limited user access and so on..)

Comment: but anyway.. what you suggest?

Comment: I didn't say you were lying; however, unless you copied the source files rather than reconstructing the program manually, it is possible that you are mistaken about the code being identical. In any case, that's why you're getting the error message when you try to use `localhost`. I'm not sure about the other error...

Comment: Where's your `AcceptCallback()` method?

Comment: Can you add the code where you are calling `StartClient` as that is the important part. Show us how you are getting the 'host` variable.

Comment: The second exception `Operation not allowed on unconnected sockets.` is from the stream you are using to read the data with - but you haven't included that code so we can't provide any help on that. But to get that exception means the call to `StartClient` is creating the socket connection when you pass it the IP address.

Comment: @Herohtar unluckly I just copied the source code.

Comment: @itsme86 I just add the method to the original question if you need it..

Comment: @SimplyGed I add `startClient()` calling code.

Comment: @SimplyGed as Farhad evidenced below there was a cut & paste error but the code is not working even if it's fixed now.

Comment: Did you open the port on your firewall and also is any antivirus blocking this connection?

Comment: The only antivirus I got is Windows Defender and I think it share the same permission of Windows Firewall. Anyway I put source code folder inside the exclusion list of the antivirus (but nothing changed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the constructor with the "IPEndPoint" parameter. This constructor does not connect to the server automatically and you must call the "Connect" method before using the socket. That is why you are getting the error message "Operation not allowed on unconnected sockets". Also, you have provided a wrong IPEndPoint for client.
Please try this on client:

```cs
private void startClient(string host, int port)
{
    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port);

    ClientTCP = new TcpClient();

    ClientTCP.Connect(serverEndPoint);

    Reader = new StreamReader(ClientTCP.GetStream());

    Listen = true;

    listner = Listener();
}
```

You may need some exception handling here, but it should work now.

**UPDATE:**
The `ipHostInfo.AddressList` may have more than one addresses and just one of them is what you wanted. It is not necessarily the first one. I specified this manually and it works:

```cs
//string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
//IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
//IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5002);
```

Comment: thnx for the correction it was cut & paste error of mine but the code it's not working anyway (same exceptions provinding a literal name) but putting 127.0.0.1 I got a different one:  _Connection could not be established. Persistent rejection of the target computer 127.0.0.1:5002_

Comment: firewall rules allows connection to my server binary.

Comment: Good @weirdgyn, Are you sure the server is listening on port number 5002? Please, check the value of "Properties.Settings.Default.Port". You are using the same port number for local and listening. This may be another bug.

Comment: I just checked it now in **Debug** and yes `Properties.Settings.Default.Port` is set to **5002**... I'm sure there's a bug somewhere but I cannot understand where. I'll put the whole code in a shared folder.

Comment: Please check it at the run time. I am rereading your source code to see if I can find anything or not.

Comment: Yes I tested it in **Debug** . I'm not running it in **Release** mode.

Comment: Please run the server-side only and try to connect with the telnet. See if you can connect to the server by telnet or not?

Comment: Trying now with `putty.exe` using `telnet` connection on port `5002` to host `TUX` (my machine name) and looks like it's connecting.

Comment: I tested your code and the only problem I have found is related to `IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];`. Please, replace that with `IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");`. I'will update the answer.